# Postman not working after Chrome 52 upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, postman

407 error seen at Postman after I installed Chrome 52.
Anyone else seeing proxy issues with postman with latest versions of Chrome?
How can I resolve it?

Comment: I using Postman is normal, not matter a version chrome and connection proxy yes. Check real postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog or try `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --show-app-list`

Answer (score 0):

Someone told  a solution 
It can be fixed by installing "Interceptor" (satellite-like image icon around top-right of postman)